# What open source tools are available for writers on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

There's the Scrivener-alternative [Manuskript](http://www.theologeek.ch/manuskript/).

Are there any other tools available on Ubuntu such as those mentioned [in this list](https://itsfoss.com/open-source-tools-writers/)?

Comment: see https://github.com/olivierkes/manuskript/issues/115

Comment: I'm having a hard time imagining what an answer to this question should say. Judging by the comments, you have two distinct requests, *a.* help getting Manuskript working, which may or may not have been resolved in the comments, and *b.* software recommendations for a vaguely defined purpose. I am voting to leave your question closed therefore because it's too broad. If *b.* is the only part of the question that remains, please edit it to remove part *a.*, and elaborate on what features you need in the software you want us to recommend.

Comment: The question is purely about software recommendations. I can't delete people's comments. This question is meant to help authors looking to switch to Ubuntu. The link provided contains examples for software commonly used. I don't understand why you would vote to keep this closed ...

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. I will flag the comments as not needed. You have provided a list... do you want us to supply additional items for the list, recommend our favourites from the list...? This is not a good question for this site's format as is. Vague requests for apps tend to attract spam, long lists, opinion-based answers... You could [edit] it to give a list of features you want, then you could get appropriate recommendations, and I would definitely vote to reopen your question